# Пользователь прокрутил до конца страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как определить что пользователь прокрутил страницу до конца вниз?

Comment: Вот страница, http://tmp.neatek.ru/ , там код срабатывает на scroll top, а не низ.

Answer (score 1):

у вас есть значение $(window).scrollTop(), содержащее количество пикселей, насколько страница прокручена от верхнего края, значение $(window).height(), очевидно, что это высота окна, и значение $(document).height(), содержащее высоту всего документа.

Простое арифметическое действие:

```
if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height()){
    console.log('ура! конец страницы!')
}
```

Comment: На http://stackoverflow.com/ мне сказали задать DOCTYPE, и это верное решение. Так как js код был верным. Ибо если не задать DOCTYPE, длина страницы будет равна 0.

Comment: ну и конечно же, проверку осуществлять на само событие прокрутки:

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height()){
            console.log('ура! конец страницы!')
        }
    })

Comment: доктайп обязательно задавайте всегда. Вам правильно там сказали.

Comment: Елена, проблема уже решена) Спасибо за ваши старания помочь.
Js код верный, не был задан DOCTYPE.
(никогда б не подумал чтобы без него не работал js код) Я просто по большинству на php пишу.

Comment: js-код работать будет, просто сам рендеринг html/css происходит иначе (примерно как в ИЕ5), если доктайп не задан, и из-за этого некоторые результаты могут казаться неожиданными.